# Mongoose Filter Not Working With Find Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing code with node.js and mongoose module. My used module is "find" method but mongo is getting all data to me so filter is not working. What is problem ?

Example Codes:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeV1').then(res=>console.log("Connection Success")).catch(e=>console.log("Error"))

const dbSchema = mongoose.Schema({},{collection:'users'})
const dbModel = mongoose.model('users',dbSchema)


dbModel.find({age:'28'},{age:1},(err,res)=>{
    console.log(res)
})
```

Result:

```
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4daab"), age: 27 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4daac"), age: 40 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4daad"), age: 24 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4daae"), age: 28 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4daaf"), age: 20 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4dab0"), age: 26 },
  { _id: new ObjectId("62eaad6af17720bd31d4dab1"), age: 32 },
```

You'r seeing data is all data arrived

What is problem ?

Comment: My datas : prnt.sc/9LC6Ufo2QdUl 

get data : prnt.sc/ab4nfmclx3g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply update your code to this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeV1').then(res => console.log("Connection Success")).catch(e => console.log("Error"))

const dbSchema = mongoose.Schema({ age: Number }, { collection: 'users' })
const dbModel = mongoose.model('users', dbSchema)

dbModel.find({
    $or: [
        { age: 28 }, { age: 1 }
    ]
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(res)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [the `$in` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), and put the values in an array, like:

```
dbModel.find({
        age: { $in:[ 28, 1] },
    },(err,res)=>{
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but this is not working again fetched all the data.  There's a mistake i can't found

Comment: My datas : https://prnt.sc/9LC6Ufo2QdUl

get data :  https://prnt.sc/ab4nfmclx3g-

Comment: Now I notice that you use an empty schema. Maybe that is causing the problem (too). You might try: `const dbSchema = mongoose.Schema({ age: Number },{collection:'users'})`

Comment: You need to remove the `{age: 1},` from your query in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might late but if you are using latest mongoose version.
Please read [migration to 6 guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#strictquery-is-removed-and-replaced-by-strict)

Plus You are searching by `string` on `number` field. Ignoring fact  it might solve problem.

**Problem explained:**

```
dbModel.find({age:'28'})
```

which emulates to

```
dbModel.find()
```

when you have non-existing key in query you can try one of these solutions

```
// for global
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)

// or for individual query
await dbModel.find({ age: 28 }, null, { strictQuery: false });

// or
await dbModel.find({ age: 28 }, null, { strictQuery: false });
```